# Virtual inheritance bug in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It seems that my problem is a bug in MSVC. I'm using the Visual Studio 2008 with Service Pack 1, and my code works with GCC (as tested on [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/E3nwI8IF)).

Any official info on this bug? Any ideas how to work around it? Is the bug fixed in VS2010? All insights would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual Base *clone() const = 0;

protected:
    int i;
};

struct A : virtual public Base {
    A() {}
    virtual A *clone() const = 0;
};

struct B : public A {
    B() {}
    B *clone() const { return new B(*this); }

    /// MSVC debugger shows that 'b' is for some reason missing the Base
    /// portion of it's object ("Error: expression cannot be evaluated")
    /// and trying to access 'b.i' causes an unhandled exception.
    ///
    /// Note: This only seems to occur with MSVC
    B(const B &b) : Base(b.i), A() {}
};

void foo(const A &elem) {
    A *a = elem.clone();
    if (a) delete a;
}

int main() {
    A *a = new B;
    foo(*a);
    delete a;
}
```

Comment: Still does that in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I noted that codepad uses g++ 4.1.2, so I tried with Borland C++ 5.82 and it works fine.

Comment: You might want to submit a bug to MS via https://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: B* and A* are covariant, so I deleted my post.  This does appear to be a bug.  I have a very hard time believing things like this are bugs, but I haven't been able to find a defect in your code.

Comment: Just as an aside and possibly a hint as to the nature of this bug, when compiling on Warning Level 4 MSVC complains that: "main.cpp(16) : warning C4505: 'A::clone' : unreferenced local function has been removed"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though the compiler is not correctly adjusting the `this` pointer when calling through `A::clone`. If you remove the declaration of `A::clone` then everything works fine.

Digging in deeper, when you have `A::clone`, the vtable looks like this:

```
    [0x0]   0x002f1136 [thunk]:B::`vector deleting destructor'`vtordisp{4294967292,0}' (unsigned int)   void *
    [0x1]   0x002f11e0 [thunk]:B::clone`vtordisp{4294967292,0}' (void)  void *
    [0x2]   0x002f12ad [thunk]:B::clone`vtordisp{4294967292,4}' (void)  void *
    [0x3]   0x002f12a3 B::clone(void)   void *
```

And foo calls `elem.__vfptr[2]`, offsetting `this` incorrectly by -4 bytes. Without `A::clone`, the vtable looks like this:

```
    [0x0]   0x00ee1136 [thunk]:B::`vector deleting destructor'`vtordisp{4294967292,0}' (unsigned int)   void *
    [0x1]   0x00ee11e0 [thunk]:B::clone`vtordisp{4294967292,0}' (void)  void *
    [0x2]   0x00ee12a3 B::clone(void)   void *
```

And foo calls `elem.__vfptr[1]`. That does not adjust `this` at all (and the code assumes that `this` will be equal to `Base` instead of `B`).

So it looks like the compiler assumes that `A::clone` is a new virtual method and doesn't override `Base::clone` when determining whether `A` requires a new virtual table, but then some other code later determines that `A` does not need a virtual table. You can verify this by comparing `sizeof(B)` with or without a new virtual function:

```
struct A : virtual public Base {
    A() {}
    virtual A *clone() const = 0;
}; //sizeof(B)==16

struct A : virtual public Base {
    A() {}
    virtual A *clone() const = 0;
virtual const A *clone2() const { return this; }
}; //sizeof(B)==20
```

So it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem (from some testing) that the bug is caused by the combination of a virtual base class with a pure virtual method using covariant return types.

Since dropping either the pure virtual method from the Base class, or making Base a non-virtual base class or making the clone() method non-covariant seems to solve the bug.

I guess this one's solved for me (after I submit a bug report to MS), and I'm even left with a few options to circumvent it. :)